# Facebook Likebox deprecation

Tags: facebook, facebook-likebox, deprecation-warning

My company uses the facebook likebox on many of our pages. The developer website https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-box-for-pages says that the likebox will automatically revert to the new pages plugin. Can someone from FB please confirm that 1. it will, and 2. whether it will change anything. Currently, we load the likebox via iframe. 
Thanks

Comment: I think you are looking for Facebook customer support - I'm not too sure that the users of [so] will be able to provide you with that information. It's true that there are a handful of official Facebook employees on [so] but the moment you are asking a direct question to a very small group of users it's less of a community driven issue and more of a specific customer based support question.

Comment: Unfortunately, Facebook has specifically linked to SO for support.

Comment: For *technical* support - yes. But you are not necessarily talking about a technical issue. It sounds to me more like a usage issue.

Comment: I fully appreciate your frustration - it's true that they blindly send people to [so] for help and then the community here shoots down non technical/programming posts...

Comment: 1. Why do you need “confirmation” for something the official docs already state? 2. My educated guess would be,that it doesn’t matter what way of embedding the plugin you use – if you put an iframe into your pages directly, the URL of the old plugin will most likely just automatically redirect to the URL of the new one. (And replace any missing parameters with default values while doing so.)

Comment: The current plugin uses an iframe, the new plugin does not. We started converting to the new plugin, and noticed some padding issues. My educated guess was that it would "just work" like the docs said. But let's be honest, when do things "just work" the way the were supposed to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why the documentation is not clear to you. It answers both your questions.

1. Yes; it will do as it says. Why would the official documentation be wrong on that?
2. Well... it will change the like-box to the Page Plugin. I would advise you to already implement the Page Plugin (perhaps on a test page) to see what it will look like on your site.

Comment: I assume that it will show _something_ but the likebox has styling that is associated with it. I changed 1 test page, and the styling changed. Easily fixed for the one test page, but we use it on 100+ pages and were very recently made aware of this change that will break in <23 days. Since the facebook page says to come here for answers, or join their private group, which I'm waiting to be accepted, I was hoping to get a little more on _how_ it will degrade, so we can jump on the most drastic;y changed pages first.

Comment: What you are doing now is best; change it per page already, so that you have control when you want to make the shift exactly.